# MSGraph findMeetingTimes API return 500 Error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-restapi

I am using the graph API's findmeetingTimes to get free/busy time.

If there is an event set in seconds in the time range within the range specified by the Timeslots parameter,500 error will be returned

For example, if I send following request :
   POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/findMeetingTimes

```
{
  "attendees": [],
  "timeConstraint": {
    "timeslots": [
      {
        "start": {
          "dateTime": "2018-07-19T09:00:00.000Z",
          "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "end": {
          "dateTime": "2018-07-19T21:00:00.000Z",
          "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "meetingDuration": "PT1H"
}
```

API returns following RESPONSE :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
        "message": "An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "43a1699f-2241-4c59-8450-826612466f07",
            "date": "2018-07-19T02:16:22"
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Calencar（Only 1 event on July 19, 2018）
   Get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview?startdatetime=2018-07-19T00:00:00.000Z&enddatetime=2018-07-19T23:59:59.999Z

```
・
・
・
"start": {
    "dateTime": "2018-07-19T12:00:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
},
"end": {
    "dateTime": "2018-07-19T12:33:33.0000000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
}
・
・
・
```

It also happens with outlookAPI

This seems like a bug to me.
Is this a known bug, and are there any plans to fix it?
Is there a known work around?

Comment: Getting the same issue both on beta and v1 endpoints event if I only specify the timeConstraint. Testing using the Graph Explorer. The same exact request works on different tenants I have. It has to be related to the data/configuration somehow. request id 25fb578c-8a1b-46f0-90f9-de91bad4ae07. I'm going to try push that internally to Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the timezone label in the time slot, UTC doesn't seem to work for some reason. At this point it's not clear whether it's a gap in the documentation or an issue with the API itself. 
 I opened a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3258) to have Microsoft investigate

Comment: things started working again with the internal discussion I had with Microsoft, not sure if they changed anything at this point